# How to automatically insert values into latex code/template

Tags: python, parsing

I'm in the process of generating an automated report in pdf from latex. Each report is the same, but has different values/graphs. The graphs is no problem, but what is the best way to process a latex template and insert values on predefined places?

Any ideas on how you would do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use any template-enabled language such as `php`, `ruby` (through `erb`),  `python` (through `String.Template` in the standard library or any of the myriad of python template libraries), if you are comfortable with those languages. You can also make it from pure latex. You should better describe your actual layout and data.

Comment: You can use a template as JLDiaz mentioned or additionally the other way around by inserting python into LaTeX documents, e.g. [PythonTeX](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex).

Answer (score 4):

***NOTE:** This question was originally asked in stackoverflow.com with a `python` tag, hence the python angle*

You should use the [str.format method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) method. For example

```
>>> msg = r"""\section{{{section}}}
... 
... An unladen swallow needs to beat its wings {frequency} times every second,
... right?""".format(section="Aviation", frequency=43)
>>> print msg
\section{Aviation}

An unladen swallow needs to beat its wings 43 times every second,
right?
```

Literal curly brackets need to be doubled, and I use `r` in front of the triple quotes ([raw strings](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)) to avoid having to escape the backslashes when the next letter happens to be for example `n`, `r` or `t`.

---

**Re: comment**

I guess I would define a new LaTeX command with two arguments. The output of the command is simply the content of the second argument:

```
\newcommand{\mergefield}[2]{#2}
```

Then I'd use the first argument as a field name when the file is used as a template.

Now if you want to change the section heading when you generate your reports, instead of this code:

```
\section{Normal section heading}
```

Use this code:

```
\section{\mergefield{section_3}{Normal section heading}}
```

After reading the file we need to do two replacements to get it as a python `str.format` template string:

1. Double all `{` and `}` characters so that they won't be interpreted as fields by `str.format`.
2. Replace all `\mergefield{{abc}}{{xyz}}` commands with the field `{abc}`

Example:

```
# This would be read from file normally...
template = r"\section{\mergefield{section_3}{Default section heading}}"

# Double curly braces
template = template.replace("{", "{{").replace("}", "}}")

# Replace template field markers with `str.format` fields.
template = re.sub(
    r"\\mergefield\{\{([^}]+)\}\}\{\{[^}]*\}\}", "{\\1}", template)
```

Now `template` is equal to `'\section{{{section}}}'`, and we can do as I first suggested to format the template.

```
>>> template.format(section_3="My custom section title")
'\section{My custom section title}'
```

Your fields names may contain any character but curly braces.

Comment: The problem is: I need the tex files to be compilaable without the information, because other guys in team will be encharged of the tex file. I will use python to read line by line, look for a special pattern, parse it, and insert the value, then print to a new tex file and compile it. Thanks.

Comment: Which character would be better for parse?

Comment: @otmezger See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like formatting a string. It doesn't really matter that it is a latex document. You can read how to format strings (which includes inserting values at predefined places) [>here<](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Edit: changed the link to the new improved string formatting api. (Thanks Lauritz V. Thaulow)

Comment: I would not recommend using the old string formatting, which is due to be [deprecated](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changes-already-present-in-python-2-6). New projects should use the improved [str.format method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) instead.